# Continue sentence with a (local variable string in the middle)

Tags: c#

The only way that I seem to find without a error is by having it split with another Console.WriteLine and then it appears in two separate lines?

```
Console.WriteLine("What Colour would you like your {0:C}", player); 
Console.WriteLine("to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?");
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see what you want, even in pseudo-code.

Comment: And please show the code that gave an error. There are lots of alternatives here.

Comment: Use string concatenation or interpolation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
Console.WriteLine("What Colour would you like your {0:C} to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?", player);
```

Or even better, in c# 6 (visual studio 2015 or higher):

```
Console.WriteLine($"What Colour would you like your {player:C} to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?");
```

Comment: Toda. This works!!!
I know I am not very articulate (especially, as English is my 3rd language and I am only starting to learn programming now )and I appreciate your help.
If I want to add a additional string in the middle of the sentence, would I do it the same way

Comment: Yes. Glad to help

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
Console.WriteLine($"What Colour would you like your {player:C} to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?");
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain old [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings) should work just fine, assuming that `player` is a string.

```
Console.WriteLine($"What Colour would you like your {player:C} to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
   Console.WriteLine($"What Colour would you like your {player} to be?\n Black \n Brown\n White\n or mixed?");
```

Comment: It won't work, add `"` before `)`

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that mistake